# how do I go from CDG airport to Montparnasse gare quickly and cheaply?

Tags: trains, france, airport-transfer, paris, cdg

I am coming from India. My flight will land at terminal 2 of Charles De Gaulle airport, Paris. From there I will go to Montparnasse gare where I have TGV train for Rennes. My flight will land at 9.30 am and my TGV train is booked at 3 pm from Montparnasse. So there is enough time I hope.

I would like go from CDG airport to Montparnasse Gare within 2 hours, non-stop or 1-stop (like RER train, Bus etc) and of course I would prefer it to be cheap.

Comment: Did you already budget for time to deplane, go through passport control, wait for your bags and go through customs in addition to those 2 hours, or do those 2 hours include all of that? Have you already booked your train? There are direct trains from CDG to Rennes, it might be much easier that way (not necessarily faster, though). At what time and on what day are you planning to do this? Are you alone? Do you have lots of bags?

Comment: @jcaron, Please see my edited question where I add my flight landing time and TGV train time. Please see it and confirm me. Yes I booked already because it was cheapest to go to Rennes from CDG via Montparnasse at the time of booking. Yes I am alone and just one  53 x 30 trolly bag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options include:

- [Le Bus Direct line 4](https://www.lebusdirect.com/lignes-horaires/ligne-cdg-aeroport-paris-gare-montparnasse.html), which will get you directly from CDG to Gare Montparnasse in about 1h30, depending on traffic. Cost is 18 euros.
- RER B from CDG to Denfert-Rochereau, then line 6 to Gare Montparnasse. A bit cheaper ([10,30€](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/airport-tickets), the ticket is valid to any metro station), and not dependent on traffic, but you need to change trains, with a couple of stairs to climb.

  Note that all RER B trains from CDG go through Paris and stop at all stations inside Paris, including Denfert-Rochereau. However, some trains are non-stop to Gare du Nord, while other have many stops. It's usually worth it to wait a few minutes more for the non-stop (much less crowded).

  Note also that there are two metro lines going from Denfert-Rochereau to Montparnasse-Bienvenüe. However, you **really** want to use line 6 and not line 4: line 6 gets you very very close to the train station, while line 4 gets you quite a distance away, with lots of stairs, corridors and a long moving walkway to get to the train station.

  When you exit customs at CDG T2, it's very easy to get to the train station: from terminals 2A, 2C, 2F, take a right after customs. From terminals 2B, 2D, 2E, take a left. Walk straight ahead following the signs to the train station, and you'll get there in a few minutes.

  Make sure you use use the windows/machines for the RER (quite clearly marked "trains to Paris") and not the long distance ones.
- a taxi: fixed cost of 55 euros, faster than the bus as it doesn’t make a detour via Gare de Lyon, but still very dependent on traffic.
- Uber and similar services but it probably won’t be much cheaper than a taxi, and slower as they are not allowed to use bus lanes.

Comment: If I prefer RER B from CDG, can I buy ticket of final destination (Montparnasse gare)  i.e., can go with single ticket from CDG to  Montparnasse? Secondly, Can I use my ATM Debit card to buy RER train ticket ?  Thanks

Comment: Given you have 5 1/2 hours your main worry is not to get bored. You’ll arrive at Montparnasse probably around 12:00. What are you going to do to pass these 3 hours? Check if your train ticket can be modified. Often taking an earlier train is just a matter of exchanging your ticket at a machine.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Yes, you can buy a single ticket that will include both RER and metro. Any standard ticket « to Paris » will do. If your debit card is linked to the Visa or MasterCard networks it should work everywhere they take cards in France (make sure your bank does not require you to notify them before you leave... some banks will block foreign transactions unless you’ve warned them before). Maestro cards should work also in most places.

Comment: @KristvanBesien, thanks for comment. Unfortunately there was no train at 1 pm or 2 pm on that date. But it is ok because there may be some shortage of time due to any uncertain problem like trafic etc

Comment: @jcaron, thanks. Yes I have an International Debit card which is permissible for transaction in abroad

Comment: If your travel runs smooth and you do not have a lot of luggage, there is the option to go up the Tour Montparnas. It is not at the station but fairly near. (I would look to leave my luggage at the station, if possible.)

Comment: When are you travelling? There normally is a TGV to Rennes at 12:52. Note that train deparure times in Europe use the 24h clock, and that there is no train at 3pm.